# Session cookie can not delete on IOS. (iPhone & iPad)

Tags: php

I use php to set and unset cookie on my website. But on IOS it can not unset.

This my code.

```
$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;

setcookie( 'branch_id', '', time() - 3600, '/', $domain, false );
unset( $_COOKIE[ 'branch_id' ] );
```

Comment: You don't know that, @hanifzekri, if `$_COOKIE[ 'branch_id' ]` is not explicitly unset, it will remain set during the current script run, even after deleting the cookie via `setcookie` before.

Comment: This is wrong. The `$_COOKIE` superglobal will still have the original value in it. It's the value it had at the time of the request. But I guess that's beyond the scope of the OP's question.

Comment: The `$_COOKIE` superglobal **will not** be empty after calling `setcookie` to delete the cookie, it will retain its **original** value. `setcookie` does not care about the superglobal at all.

Answer (score 0):

First off: The fifth parameter of `setcookie` is of type `string`, why should your ternary return `false` on localhost?

I've tried with a simplified version in Mobile Safari on iPhone and iPad. This sets the cookie as expected:

```
setcookie('test_cookie', '1234', time()+600, '/');
```

and this deletes the cookie as expected:

```
setcookie('test_cookie', '', time()-600, '/');
unset($_COOKIE['test_cookie']);
```

As for the comment by `hanif zekri`, the `unset` would be redundant: That's wrong!

```
var_dump($_COOKIE['test_cookie']);
setcookie('test_cookie', '', time()-600, '/');
var_dump($_COOKIE['test_cookie']);
unset($_COOKIE['test_cookie']);
var_dump($_COOKIE['test_cookie']);
```

returns

```
string(4) "1234"
string(4) "1234"
NULL
```

`$_COOKIE['test_cookie']` will retain its original value (from time of request) even after deleting the cookie with `setcookie()` for the remainder of the script. `setcookie()` does not influence the superglobal at all.

Comment: No `$_COOKIE` is `an associative array of variables passed to the current script via HTTP Cookies`, but it's not being altered by the `setcookie()` function as you implied. Correcting your wrong comment is just an add-on to my answer.

Comment: The OP posted a ternary which can return `false` and is being passed as the **fifth** parameter to `setcookie()`. I was **not** referring to the sixth parameter, which is indeed the `secure` parameter and **does** default to `false` (so there's no need to pass that explicitly as the OP did). And there's no problem with simply emptying a cookie value (as far as I am concerned), but it has nothing to do with the question nor with the unset issue.

Comment: What are you talking about? The OP's actual problem or the unset nonsense?

Comment: `/` is not a valid domain also. Don't know if that's the OP's problem anyways, passing `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is unnecessary as you could simply set the domain parameter to '' or leave it out at all. Since the example in my answer works (and their's allegedly doesn't), they should check it. We simply don't know what `$domain` evaluates to in their setup.